# Stacked 2d-sigmoidal function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for a real-valued function that maps from the [-1,1]^2 domain to the real number line segment [-1,1]. The following mappings should be fullfilled:

(-1,-1) --> -1

(1,1) --> 1

(1,-1) --> 0

(1,-1) --> 0

My idea was to use two coupled sigmoidal functions, but i don't get how to connect them correctly. Has anyone an idea for me?

Ideally it would look something like this here:
[Surface of 3d function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1STA.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

This is a mapping of a function $f(x,y)$ from a square region $-1\le x,y\le 1$ which is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. So the simplest answer is $f(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)$.